# What Divided Political Sphere means

Tags: terminology, political-system

Can anyone describe what "Divided Political Sphere" means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Sphere" in this context is typically short hand for "[Sphere of Influence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphere_of_influence)" which historically tended to refer to literal territory that a political entity had influence over but has been broadened to include more abstract concepts. One such example being the (IMHO) cringe-worth "blogosphere" or "twittersphere" which refers to the influence amateur web-reporting has on news. Another example would be the range of influence a major corporation in a particular sector may have on that industry.

A divided one would mean there are factions within. In the case of a divided political sphere, it would typically refer to divisions amongst popular, influential parties or movements within (or on the edges) of the political process.